# Actualicé mi web pero se muestra una versión antigua

Tags: php, html, wordpress, cache

Actualicé mi pagina pero se muestra una versión antigua. Estoy trabajando con Wordpress.

Estoy usando `Chrome` y todo se ve correcto. Sin embargo en `Edge` me muestra una versión antigua de la página ¿como lo sé? pues, hice una comparación de codigo fuente de la página principal en ambos navegadores, y en `Edge` me muestra código que apenas existió hasta anoche, mientras que en `Chrome` me muestra lo que hay actualmente.

¿Y cómo sé que el código que se muestra en `Edge` era el de anoche? Pues, anoche desinstalé el plugin `All in One SEO` que viene por defecto en las nuevas instalacioners de WordPress y hoy, a través de `Edge`, se sigue mostrando la metadata en la página principal:

```
<!-- All in One SEO 4.2.0 -->
...
...
...
...
<!-- All in One SEO -->
```

En `Edge` tampoco se muestran algunas imagenes que actualicé en la página, e incluso los enlaces los remplacé pero siguen apareciendo los antiguos.

Sin embargo en `Chrome` no se muestran esos datos de `AIOSEO`, y todas las imagenes cargan correctamente con todo lo que actualicé, sólo se muestra lo que se debe mostrar, como tiene que ser.

Creyendo que era un problema de chaché decidí refrezcarla con `F5` pero no funcionó, también usé `CCleaner` para limpiar los datos del navegador y no funcionó, abrí y guardé los enlaces permanentes de Wordpress (sin tocar nada) y no funcionó, hice lo mismo con lectura y escritura por las dudas, y no funcionó. Hice todo lo que estaba a mi alcance.

Sin embargo el problema empeora porque varias personas ya han entrado a la página y tienen exactamente el mismo problema que tengo en mi navegador `Edge`. Esto ocurre con todos los navegadores incluido `Chrome`, por lo tanto descarto que sea un problema del navegador.

Incluso estoy actualizando parte del código de mi `index` y en `Chrome` los cambios se reflejan inmediatamente, pero no en Edge, y tampoco se le reflejan a las personas que la estan entrando desde otros paises.

Acá una imagen de cómo se tiene que ver, esto es usando `Chrome`, y así lo veo actualmente:

[image: asi se ve en mi chrome]

Acá una imagen de cómo se muestra en mi navegador `Edge`, así lo veo actualmente y así también lo ven mis compañeros en otras partes del mundo:

[image: asi se ve en mi edge]

Ya no se que más puedo hacer, en este punto ni siquiera sé qué buscar exactamente. Simplemente en Edge se muestra lo antiguo, y a otras personas tambien les sucede lo mismo. En mi `Chrome` se muestra de manera correcta, pero a otros no.

Acá mi página para que puedan entrar:

https://tiblioteca.com/

¿Alguien tiene una idea de lo que está ocurriendo? ¿Por qué no se reflejan los cambios que estoy haciendo? ¿por qué en uno de mis navegadores sí se muestra y en el otro no? ¿por qué a los demás no se les reflejan los cambios que estoy realizando?

Comment: el error que mostras, parece un html mal formado. sin embargo, si en uno de tus navegadores se ve bien, quiere decir que estas actualizando algo en algun lado, pero no en el mismo lado donde estan buscando todos.. puede seR?

Comment: @gbianchi gracias compañero, pero no se trata de html mal formado, de lo contrario se vería mal en todos los navegadores. El problema tenia que ver con la Caché y un par de plugins en WordPress, coloqué la solución abajo. Aprecio que te hayas tomado el tiempo de leer y responder, de verdad. Saludos!

Comment: Has probado borrando la caché del sitio? Es posible que en Edge estés almacenando una versión anterior en caché y por eso se ve de esa manera. Prueba entrando en modo incógnito en ambos navegadores

Comment: La solución va en la parte inferior. Luego esperas 24 horas para marcar la respuesta como aceptada. Saludo.

Comment: PD: Dale recuperar a la respuesta que eliminaste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**La solución:**

Ayer desativé `LiteSpeed Cache`, que viene por defecto en las nuevas instalaciones de `WordPress`, y mantuve activo `W3 Total Cache` que venia usando desde hace tiempo.

Simplemente desactivé `W3 Total Cache` y activé `LiteSpeed Cache`.

Probablemente el fallo se deba a que borré la carpeta de la caché de `W3 Total Cache` cuando subí por `FTP` los archivos de mi instalación de `WordPress`, esto con el fin de reducir el peso del archivo, cosa que funcionó de maravillas. Sin embargo lo que hice fue reemplazar los nuevos archivos con los viejos y en ese caso ya estaba la carpeta de archivos de `W3 Total Cache` con la caché antigua (en el hosting), y probablemente por eso se cargaba de manera correcta en `Chrome`, ya que también es mi navegador por defecto, y especulo que de alguna manera habrán quedado "residuos" de cargas anteriores, pese a que pasé `Ccleaner`, pero creo que lo tengo configurado para que no borre la chaché de `Chrome` por varios motivos.

Mi experiencia con `Microsoft Edge` apenas comenzó anoche cuando quise probra cómo se vería mi página en otro navegador, y con `W3 Total Cache` activo pero sin archivos de caché dentro y en un nuevo navegador, asumo que era "normal" hasta cierto punto que se mostraran esos errores, ya que no se había generado ninguna caché y `W3 Total Cache` estaba configurado para leer archivos que yo mismo borré. Creo que entró en conflicto.

En cambio `LiteSpeed Cache` es nuevo en mi instalación y comenzó a hacer las cosas sin conflictos de lectura ni nada extraño, tanto en `Chrome` como en `Edge`.